# Selenium - Click list item from unordered list - Java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, html-lists

I am trying to click on an option (array of images) from an unordered list using Selenium Java.

[image]

[image]

I have tried doing a click on the className of "attachment" but that doesn't seem to pick up the list item that I need to click on.

Is there anyway to pick up something like the data-id?

The code that I have tried:

```
public void click(By by) {
    waitProvider.waitFor().waitUntilElementIsClickable(by);
    WebElement clickableElement = locate(by);
    Actions actions = new Actions(webDriverProvider.driver());
    actions.moveToElement(clickableElement);
    actions.click().perform();
}
```

and then we do:

```
public void selectFirstImage() {
    click("attachment");
}
```

locate:

```
public WebElement locate(By by) {
    waitProvider.waitFor().waitUntilVisibilityOfElementLocatedBy(by);
    scrollIntoView(by);
    return webDriverProvider.driver().findElement(by);
}
```

Comment: What is your exact _Manual Step_ which you are trying to _Automate_?

Comment: I have a list of images on a screen... (all clickable) put together in the ul above. the li is an example of an image.. I just need to click on this image (so its selectable)

Comment: Can you share code sample?
Without that I can only suggest using css selector `css=".attachment-preview"`.
But this is also a guess, as I don't know if actual `img` is under `div` or `button`.

Comment: Please provide some more HTML, and some code sample.

Comment: @mvoase why do you use Action class to click. you could have tried with web element click.

Answer (score 0):

I think `click` method call is incorrect.
Since click expects `By` not `String` it should look like this:

```
click(new ByCssSelector(".attachment-preview"));
```

Comment: Sorry my apologies... "attachment" is actually define globally using By.

Comment: ^^ static field? how defined? Have you tried debugging your code to see if `clickableElement` is actually found?

Comment: but you are passing attachment as string here.

Comment: Like this : private static final By MEDIA_ATTACHMENT = By.className("attachment");

Comment: And no it doesn't find the element.

Comment: So the problem is in locate method, can you share it?

Comment: Added locate above.

Comment: Can you try and change locator to look for list elements? To see if anything in that place in DOM can be located?